# Cascading form generation - Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I have website based on Symfony2 framework which have three level category system. Now I want to create form for creating of new product. Product carry information about his Category, Subcategory and also Subsubcategory too.

So, the goal is to create form which automatically generates choices for Subcategory and Subsubcategory based on previous choose (when I choose category, subcategory choices for that category are generated, when I choose Subcategory choices for Subsubcategory are generated). Subcategory choices are generated properly (I followed Symfony2 documentation: I used Form Events). I don't know how to properly setup events for Subsubcategory entity.

Here is my code (JavaScript is working fine so I skipped it):

**ProductType snippet:**

```
        $categoryFormModifer = function(FormInterface $formInterface, Category $category = null) {
        $subcategories = null == $category ? array() : $category->getSubcategories();
        $formInterface->add('idSubcategory', 'entity', array(
            'label' => "Podkategória",
            'class' => 'SalalajDefaultBundle:Subcategory',
            'choice_label' => 'subTitle',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices' => $subcategories,
        ));
    };

    $builder->get('idCategory')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($categoryFormModifer) {
            $categoryFormModifer($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
        }
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($categoryFormModifer) {
            /**
             * @var $data Product
             */
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $categoryFormModifer($form, $data->getIdCategory());
            $subcategory = $data->getIdSubcategory();
            $form->add('idSubsubcategory', 'entity', array(
                'label' => "Podpodkategoria",
                'class' => 'SalalajDefaultBundle:Subsubcategory',
                'choice_label' => 'ssbTitle',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $subcategory ? $subcategory->getIdSubsubcategory() : array()
            ));
        }
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            /**
             * @var $subcategory Subcategory
             */
            if (!in_array('idSubcategory', $data))
                return;
            $subcategory = $data['idSubcategory'];
            $form->add('idSubsubcategory', 'entity', array(
                'label' => "Podpodkategoria",
                'class' => 'SalalajDefaultBundle:Subsubcategory',
                'choice_label' => 'ssbTitle',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $subcategory ? $subcategory->getIdSubsubcategory() : array(),
            ));
        }
    );
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you'll have to make an AJAX call to populate the sub-select choices, when an onChange() event is triggered on the parent's select. Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062618/symfony2-forms-with-multiple-dependent-fields/32067434#32067434

Comment: AJAX call already exists, there was problem in PRE_SUBMIT event (I used in_array instead of array_key_exists). I will write solution post later. But thanks for your response!